# How can I integrate social features into iOS and/or Android apps without Facebook, Twitter, etc.?

Tags: android, ios, social-networking

I'm trying to evaluate various ways of adding social features to a suite of iOS and Android apps.  Rather than integrating Facebook, Twitter, or whatever, I want to have all of the activities go through my servers (or a service that I control).

Some of the things that I'd like to do within the app are:

- message other users of my apps
- share data, links, etc. across users of my apps
- see other users activities within my apps (like a news feed)

I've done some research and there are several classes of solutions, none of which seem to suit my specific needs.

- Gamification platforms like Badgeville, Big Door, etc.  These don't really work for me, because I'm not trying to get my users to do anything more than stay in the app and share a narrow range of specific content.  Also these things seem very web focused.
- Third party social network services integration.  Basically, this means putting Facebook messenger or something similar in my app.  My challenge is that I just don't want to route through some other semi-public service.  I need to stay within servers that I control.
- Social integration platforms like Janrain and gigya seem to be the closest to what I'm looking for.  They're still a bit focused on the web, and they're terribly expensive for what they offer.  Really, I would just be using them as an authentication method.

Am I missing something here?  Is there a better way of adding this little bit of social functionality to my apps?  I'd be interested in any open source options that I could host on my own servers or a commercial options hosted elsewhere.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

@user1059324 I think we have just the thing you're looking for: Socialize.  Check it out at http://www.GetSocialize and tell me if it's what you wanted.   Full feature list at http://go.GetSocialize.com/features. I'd love to hear what you think.

DROdio

Comment: This sounds more like an advertisement than like a proper answer. I think you should add more information to your posting. Well, at least post functioning links...

Comment: Till yeah so sorry -- URL obviously is www.GetSocialize.com